# R ggiraph onclick javascript -Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, ggplot2, shiny, printf

I have a *ggplot* and I try to make it interactive with *[ggiraph](https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/introduction.html)* package. The *tooltip* works fine, the ***"onclick"*** function seems to appear in the Shiny console when I click on the `geom_line`.

But I can't make it work so when I click a `geom_line_interactive`, to change(using js) the `input type`(from `search` to `submit`) and **set** the `value` of a *dataTable* `search input`.

The html of the table's `search input`:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0">
```

Make new column for js used in ***onclick*** feature:

```
dfMonth$onclick <- sprintf(
  "function clickLine(){document.getElementsByClassName(\"form-control input-sm\").type=\"submit\".value=\"%s\";}",as.character(dfMonth$ISBN) )
```

In server.R file, use the js from onclick column:

```
geom_line_interactive(aes(color=ISBN, group=ISBN, tooltip=ISBN, onclick=onclick))
```

I did try using only document.getElementsByClassName(..... without including it in a function (it has no effect on the `input` field). I can't modify the html, so I can't add an id to the input field.

Answer (score 0):

This gist demonstrate how to fill the search input field of a DT from ggiraph in shiny:

https://gist.github.com/davidgohel/68623058bad5b42f253ec8823a732a45

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. I think this can bring great possibilities to make the data even more powerful by enabling dynamic interactions between different widgets ("making htmlwidgets talk to each other"). 

I avoided the syntax error thrown for the back ticks, by changing    ``data$onclick <- paste0("set_search_val(`", data$label, "`);")`` to `data$onclick <- sprintf("set_search_val(\"%s\");",as.character(data$label))`